# Is the limit of compound Poisson random variables a compound Poisson r.v.?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limit-theorems, levy-processes

Let $Y$ be an [infinitely divisible (I.D.) random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)).

Let $\nu$ be any measure not necessarily finite: $\nu(\mathbb R)\leq \infty$. Suppose that $Y \sim (0, \nu,0)_0$ according to the notation on Page 39, Equation (8.7), from *Sato, Ken-Iti*, Lévy processes and infinitely divisible distributions, [ZBL0973.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0973.60001).

That is, the Lévy-Khintchine representation of the characteristic function is given by:
\begin{equation} \label{I}\tag{I}
\varphi_Y(z) = \exp\left\{ \int_{\mathbb R} [e^{izx} - 1] \, d\nu(x)   \right\}
\end{equation}

$\underline{Remark\,\,1:}$

> Note that if $\nu(\mathbb R)< \infty$, we can set $\lambda:=\nu(\mathbb R)$ and writte: $$ \varphi_Y(z) = \exp\left\{\lambda \int_\mathbb R [e^{izx} - 1] \, d\eta(x)   \right\}, \quad d\eta(x):= d\nu(x)/\lambda$$
> In this case, we have that $\eta$ is a probability measure ($\eta(\mathbb R)=1$) and $Y$ is a compound Poisson random variable  $Y \sim CP(\lambda, \eta)$( See page 18, Equation (4.1) from the Sato's book (reference above) or Updated remark 2 below.)

However, in general, we don't have $\nu(\mathbb  R)< \infty$. For example, see  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561024/example-of-a-levy-measure-with-infinite-mass-around-zero) and this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561609/example-of-a-levy-measure-with-infinite-mass-around-zero-but-with-finite-second), where we have infinite mass around zero.

*So my question is*: Given a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of I.D. random variables with
$$ \varphi_{X_n}(z) = \int_{\mathbb R} [e^{izx}-1 ]
\, d\nu_n(x), \quad \nu_n(\mathbb R)< \infty$$
By $\underline{Remark\,\,1}$ above, we have that $X_n \sim CP(\lambda_n, \eta_n)$ where $\lambda_n = \nu_n(\mathbb R)$ and $d\eta_n(x):= d\nu_n(x)/\lambda_n$. Now, supppose that
\begin{equation}\label{II}\tag{II}
X_n \Longrightarrow Y, \quad (n\to \infty)
\end{equation}
where $Y \sim (0, \nu,0)_0$ has characterization given by (\ref{I}).

**So, in what situations ( assumptions about $\eta_n$ and $\lambda_n$ ) the convergence given in (\ref{II}) implies that $Y$, with characterization given by (\ref{I}),  is in fact a compound Poisson random variable?** Or in other sufficient way, when we have $\nu(\mathbb  R)< \infty$?.

One trivial case is when $(X_n)$ has the same distribution. I.e. $\eta_n = \eta$  and $\lambda_n = \lambda$ for all $n$. So we exclude this case.

My intuition tells me that it is not possible, given (\ref{II}), to have $\nu(\mathbb  R)< \infty$.

Help

**Updated remarks**

$1.-$ Using the theorem 8.7, page 41, from the Sato's book (reference above)), we have that if $f \in C_\#$ (bounded continuous function vanishing on a neighborhood of $0$), then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \underbrace{\lambda_n \eta_n (dx)}_{= \nu_n (dx)} = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \nu (dx)$$

So, for  any $\epsilon>0$, taking the indicator function $f_\epsilon(x) = \chi_{|x|>\epsilon}(x)= 1 $ if $|x|>\epsilon$ and $0$ other wise, we have

$$\eta_n( E_\epsilon ) \to \nu( E_\epsilon ), \quad E_\epsilon = \{x: |x|>\epsilon\}, \quad (n \to \infty) $$

Could this be a useful way?

After the comment from Christophe Leuridan, we have to take a convenient continuous function and not the indicator function, because it is not continuous.

$2.-$ After the comment from Christophe Leuridan, I think it is necessary to specify that, in general, given a *probability* measure $\eta$,  $Y \sim CP(\lambda, \eta)$ means that:
\begin{equation}
Y  = \sum_{j=1}^N X_j, \quad N\sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda), \, X_j\,\, \text{i.i.d.} \sim \eta
\end{equation}
For more details, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution). Moreover, the characteristic function is:

$$\varphi_Y(z) = \exp\left\{\lambda \int_\mathbb R [e^{izx} - 1] \, d\eta(x)   \right\} = \exp\left\{ \lambda \int_\mathbb R e^{izx} \, d\eta(x) - 1  \right\}= \exp\left\{ \lambda [\varphi_\eta(z) - 1]  \right\} $$

$3.-$ I had posted this result above, but I don't know if it will help much. However, I will register it here. We know thar every random variable $Y$ is infinitely divisible if and only if there is a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of compound Poisson random variables such that, in  weak limits:
\begin{equation}X_n \Longrightarrow Y, \quad (n\to \infty)
\end{equation}
C.f. Theorem 16.5, page 333, from *Klenke, Achim*, [**Probability theory. A comprehensive course**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-5361-0). [ZBL1295.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1295.60001).

Comment: A good assumption is that the sequence $(\eta_n(\mathbb{R}))_{n \ge 1}$ is bounded. Without this assumption, you may have non-compound-Poisson distribution at the limit. For example, one can approach $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{izx-1}}{z^{3/2}}dx$ by $\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{izx-1}}{z^{3/2}}dx$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Note that if $X_n \sim CP(1, \eta_n)$, then $\eta_n$  is a measure, i.e., $\eta_n(\mathbb R)=1$ for all $n$. c.f. Definition 1.2 , page 4 from https://cutt.ly/dNjXB6z (this definition is for C.P process, but for r.v. is the same) So $(\eta(\mathbb R))_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded, necessarily.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the notations, and I confused the probability measure $\eta_n$ with $\lambda_n\eta_n$. If I understand correctly, you assume the total mass $\lambda_n$ to be constant.

Comment: I am assuming that $\lambda_n = 1$. I edited my question. See the update remark 2.

Comment: All right. I edited my answer to correct errors.

Comment: My impression is that your first remark gives the answer. Les $f_\epsilon$ be a continuous (hence not an indicator) function vanishing on $[-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]$ and equal to 1 on the complement of $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[$. Then $\nu(]-\epsilon,\epsilon[^c) \le \int f_\epsilon d\nu \le 1$. Since it holds for every $\epsilon>0$, $\nu(\mathbb{R}) \le 1$.

Comment: Dear, I apologize. I'm actually interested in the case where $\lambda$ is not constant equal to one. I edited the question one more time. I hope it becomes clearer. Sorry.

Comment: Do you assume that $(\lambda_n)$ is bounded or not ? If yes, I think that $\nu$ is necessarily bounded. Otherwise, it may be finite or infinite.

Comment: So I don't assume nothing about $(\lambda_n)$. Your assumption and hypothesis are interesting.

Comment: If you still interesting similar problems, please clarify your problems.

Comment: This version is more definitive and corrected. 
 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455496/a-complex-question-related-to-a-certain-convergence-of-lévy-measures-corrected

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did not make a mistake, but I think it works.

The convergence
$$\exp\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} (e^{izx}-1)d\eta_n(x) \Big) \to \exp\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} (e^{izx}-1)d\nu(x)\Big)$$ yields the convergence $$\int_\mathbb{R} (e^{izx}-1)d\eta_n(x) \to  \int_\mathbb{R} (e^{izx}-1)d\nu(x).$$
I take the real parts and change the signs to have non-negative functions.
$$\int_\mathbb{R} (1-\cos(zx))d\eta_n(x) \to \exp \int_\mathbb{R} (1-\cos(zx))d\nu(x).$$
By Fubini's theorem and Fatou's lemma, for every $T>0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_\mathbb{R} (1-(Tx)^{-1}\sin(Tx))d\nu(x) 
&=& \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} (1-\cos(zx))d\nu(x)\Big)dz \\
&=& \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \lim_n\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} (1-\cos(zx))d\eta_n(x)\Big)dz \\
&\le& \liminf_n \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \Big(\int_\mathbb{R} (1-\cos(zx))d\eta_n(x)\Big)dz \\
&=& \liminf_n \int_\mathbb{R} (1-(Tx)^{-1}\sin(Tx))d\eta_n(x) \\
&\le& 1+1/\pi,
\end{eqnarray*}
since the function sinc is bounded below by $-1/\pi$. Applying Fatou's lemma again,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_\mathbb{R} 1d\nu(x) 
&\le& \liminf_{T \to +\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} (1-(Tx)^{-1}\sin(Tx))d\nu(x) \\
&\le& \liminf_{T \to +\infty} 1+1/\pi.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\nu$ is finite. I guess that a refinement of this argument shows that $\nu(\mathbb{R}) \le 1$.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me how you get your second display from the first one, given that $\ln$ has different branches.

Comment: @Iosif Pinellis. You are right. In the second display, both sides are continuous  functions of $x$ vanishing at $0$, but the convergence is not necessarily uniform on compact sets.

Comment: @Iosif Pinellis. Yes, you are right. Although both members are continuous functions vanishing at $0$ (the function $x \mapsto \min(|x|,1)$ is assumed to be $\nu$-integrable), it is not se obvious, since we have not necessarily convergence on compact sets.

Comment: Dear, I apologize. I'm actually interested in the case where $\lambda$ is not constant equal to one. I edited the question one more time. I hope it becomes clearer. Sorry.

Comment: Losif Pinelis and  Christophe Leuridan, this question is more specific
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576471/show-that-a-levy-measure-which-arises-from-a-convergence-of-infinitely-divisibl